# OpenBook Market Pool Keys

Tags: solana-program

Is there a way to retrieve market pool keys directly from OpenBook or the Solana blockchain, regardless of whether liquidity has been added or not?

Typically, an OpenBook market is created before liquidity is added on Raydium. I assume that during market creation, all keys necessary for swapping are generated and stored.

When liquidity is added, Raydium likely retrieves this data for use in creating the liquidity pool. I would like to access this data directly but am unsure of the process.

Any alternative ideas for achieving this are also welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess the market is an address owned by the open book program. You can get all account owned by a program with connection rpc. But i guess there might be other types of account as well, so you will probably need to filter properly.